Solve $f'(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$.

If $f'(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ for all real $x \neq y$, what is $f(x)$?

I think $f(x)=ax+b$ or $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ but I really don't know how to prove it. I think it can be proved by MVT, but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone explain how to prove it?

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794975/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3954680/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/522477/42969 – all found with Approach0

In future, make it a point to look at the right-hand pane of the page for links to duplicates.
